# Optimizing windowing query in presto

Tags: sql, bigdata, presto

I have a table with fields such as user_id, col1, col2, col3, updated_at, is_deleted, day.

And current query looks like this -

```
 SELECT DISTINCT
    user_id,
    first_value(col1) ignore nulls OVER (partition BY user_id 
 ORDER BY
    updated_at DESC rows BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED following) AS col1,
    first_value(col2) ignore nulls OVER (partition BY user_id 
 ORDER BY
    updated_at DESC rows BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED following) AS col2,
    first_value(col3) ignore nulls OVER (partition BY user_id 
 ORDER BY
    updated_at DESC rows BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED following) AS col3,
    bool_or(is_deleted) ignore nulls OVER (partition BY user_id 
 ORDER BY
    updated_at DESC rows BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED following) AS is_deleted 
 FROM
    my_table
 WHERE
    day >= '2021-05-25'
```

Basically, I want the latest(first) value of each column, for each user id. Since each value column can be null, I am having to run same windowing query multiple times(for each column).
Currently, 66% of the time is being spent on windowing.
Any way to optimize?

Answer (score 0):

seems like you want this :

```
select * from (
  select * , row_number() over (partition by user_id ORDER BY updated_at DESC) rn 
  from my_table
  where day >= '2021-05-25'
) t 
where rn = 1
```

Comment: It can return NULLs which OP wants to avoid.